# idle keyboard shortcuts have changed after installing enthought

Tags: keyboard, python-idle, enthought, shortcut

I'm taking an online MIT programming course that suggested I use the enthought programming environment.  I installed it and now my idle keyboard shortcuts have all changed.  It seems to be directly caused by the installation of enthought, as my other computer (without enthought) still retained the old keyboard shortcuts.  Anyone know how to get my old keyboard shortcuts back?

Comment: Are you really saying that IDLE's keyboard shortcuts have changed? (What's an example, and what's your OS?) Or are you saying that Canopy's keyboard shortcuts are different than IDLE's?

Comment: IDLE's keyboard shortcuts are defined by tk, the IDLE code in lib/idlelib, the configuration files in idlelib, and the configuration files is $HOME/.idlerc, where $HOME is your home directory.  You can check file dates in idlelib and .idlerc directories.

Answer (score -2):

if i were you, try to continue and use your old shortcuts but if they still dont work, try to use "control" for "option" shortcuts and vice-versa. thanks to the the websites online for everything!